# Help with Views Relationships

Tags: views

I have a structure as follows:

**Taxonomy -**
Academic Programs
Occupation Classifications
*Academic Programs has a term reference field to Occupation Classifications*

**Nodes -**
Academic Homepages (*has reference to Academic Programs*)
Occupation Details (*has reference to Occupation Classifications*)

I'm trying to build a block view that will pull information from the Occupation Classifications taxonomy and the Occupation Details node. The block will display on Academic Homepages nodes.

The block is pulling in information from the Occupation Classifications taxonomy, but I can't get it to display fields from the Occupation Details node that have the same term reference to the Occupation Classification.

Here's how I have it configured currently, and I'd appreciate your help in getting fields from the Occupation Details node as part of this view.

**Contextual Filters:**
Content: Nid (default from URL)

**Relationships:**
Field: Academic Program
(Academic Program): Taxonomy term: SOC Code

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your view with the advanced fieldset expanded?

Comment: You may need an additional relationship, something like "Content:has taxonomy term", which creates the relationship between "(Academic Program): Taxonomy term: SOC Code" and the Occupation Details node tagged with that term